# Django and MySQL, cannot gain access to connect with the database ERROR:1045

Tags: python, mysql, django, connector

Hello I am working on a project with a few people. We are using django 1.9 my mysql and someone set up django to connect with mysql and then wrote instructions for the rest of us on what we need to download to connect python with mysql. I correctly installed mysql but I have issues with accessing the database. We are all suppose to have access to the DB but I keep getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'django'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")` even when I just type in mysql into the terminal I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'stevenJing'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` and typing in `mysql -u root -p` I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I am not sure on what I need to to do to fix this for I cannot even do `python3 manage.py runserver` for I get a big error which is.

```
    Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10434a510>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 264, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'django'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1178, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1255, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 925, in check
    errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 317, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 18, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 625, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 184, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 359, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 264, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'django'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Here is my settings.py for Django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       # 'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'lolProject',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'django-pass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        #'OPTIONS':{'read_default_file': ''},
        #'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

The person who set up the DB is new with MySQL and so am I, how could we get it so if anyone pulls or clones from our git repo they have access to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

### Mysql Privileges

This error is because the `django` user does not have access to the `lolProject` database. You can rectify that by using the [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) command. The django user needs a lot of privileges because it needs to create and drop tables as part of migrations so someting like this ought to do it.

```
GRANT ALL ON lolproject.* TO 'django'@'localhost';
```

**Update:** Typically you do this by opening the mysql console as `mysql -u root` where root is an account that's installed by default and usually does not have a password associated with it.

Now this will be fine if everyone is having a mysql server on their on computers. If everyone connects to the same compupter, it ought to be

```
GRANT ALL ON lolproject.* TO 'django'@'%';
```

Since everyone who pulls from your repo needs access, you ought to use an IP instead of localhost in your `settings.py`

### Sqlite

Have you considered using sqlite? It has almost no setup required and every one who clones or pulls from your repo gets a copy of the current database (if it has been added to the repo).

Comment: how would someone go about using the first command. When he types mysql into the terminal he gets blocked because he has no permissions.

Comment: Yes, you need someone with mysql admin privileges to add users and grant privileges.  Users can be granted privileges to grant other users privileges, but that's more than what you want to deal with.  I also like the sqlite idea unless you need to share your database.

Comment: SQLite is great but you will encounter problems if you are not using it in production as well. MySQL and SQLite do not mix well.

Answer (score 1):

If people are pulling your code, and you want them to access YOUR database, then they probably shouldn't be using "localhost."  If you're getting this error while running on your localhost, too, then it's a permission problem.

The first thing to do is see if you can use the command line MySQL, or another MySQL client, to log in using those credentials.

I get these kinds of errors a lot (unfortunately) and it's usually because I didn't add the user correctly in MySQL.  I noticed just putting '%' doesn't account for localhost, I usually have to add 'user'@'localhost' in addition to 'user'@'%' when granting a user privileges.

EDIT: in order to grant privileges, you need to log into mysql as root, typically you'd use something like:

```
% mysql -u root -P mysql
```

The "-P" means you will have to supply the root/admin password, that last "mysql" is the schema to use.  Obviously you need administrator access in order to do that.

Then, in more recent versions of MySQL, you first create the user:

```
> create user  'stevenJing'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

This is actually a different user than 'stevenJing'@'%', so if you're going to connect both from localhost and remote hosts, you actually need both.

Then you need to grant privileges to that user:

```
> grant all privileges on <schema>.* to 'stevenJing'@'localhost';
```

Where schema is obviously your Django schema (lolProject in your Django settings above).  Additionally, of course, to grant that user privileges to log in from elsewhere:

```
> grant all privileges on <schema>.* to 'stevenJing'@'%';
```

Comment: trying in MySQL to get to the command line does not work, I get this ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'stevenJing'@'localhost'. If I can get the person who set up the DB to give me permission how would I go about doing that.